# Google Maps fails when moving page to new url

Tags: javascript, google-maps

When I call Google Maps from the original URL http://cat.herrick.m401.signature-it.com/testmap.html , Google Maps does indeed produce a map.  However, when the same page is rendered with a new URL http://herrickindustrial.com/testmap.html , Google Maps instead produces the message "Oops! Something went wrong." with error "MissingKeyMapError".  I have tried using a new API key for the new URL, but I get the same error.  How do I get it working with the new URL?

Comment: did you set any restrictions on the type of domain name when you received the maps API key?

Comment: The authentication responses are different. signature-it.com gets `/**/_xdc_._qsin1i && _xdc_._qsin1i( [1,null,0] )` and herrickindustrial.com gets `/**/_xdc_._oxz00v && _xdc_._oxz00v( [0,15,0] )`. The code is the same, so the second domain is being blocked for some reason.

Comment: Libby, the issue occurs even with a new API key.

Comment: You have the same key on both pages. Why do you believe that key should work on both domains? Please post a [mcve] that exhibits the issue and the referrer you have specified for the key (or keys) that you believe should allow them.

Answer (score 0):

The page http://herrickindustrial.com/testmap.html loads Google Maps JavaScript API without an API key.

The URL is:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=componentGoogleMaps.initCallback&key=&sensor=false&language=en&dir=ltr&region=IL&_=1479660362171

As you can see the key parameter is empty `&key=&sensor=false...`

Check your code to figure out why the key is empty. The API key is obligatory since June 22, 2016. You have to include it.

Additionally, I would like to suggest using the [Google Maps API Checker extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps-api-checker/mlikepnkghhlnkgeejmlkfeheihlehne) for Chrome browser.

With this extension, you can check your pages and find problems related to Google Maps JavaScript API implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The [error message](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages) tells you what is wrong: `"MissingKeyMapError"`, from the the documentation:

> **MissingKeyMapError**    Error
>
> The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. **If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key.** If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

Your code isn't including the API key in its request:

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=componentGoogleMaps.initCallback&key=&sensor=false&language=en&dir=ltr&region=IL">
```

My guess would be that `http://*.signature-it.com` is grandfathered for keyless access.